# Convert Text file to Array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

New to python.I have a text file which looks something like this:

```
1   
4 
-69 
-64  
1   
5 
-57 
-56   
1   
6 
-59 
-56   
1   
7 
-69 
-61   
1   
8
-53 
-53   
1   
9 
-69 
-62   
1  
10 
-65 
-58   
1  
11 
-69 
-58
```

Want to convert it to a array using numpy which shows output something like this:

```
[[ 1 4 -69 -64 ]
[ 1 5 -57 -56 ]
[ 1 6 -59 -56 ] 
[ 1 7 -69 -61 ] 
[ 1 8 -53 -53 ] 
[ 1 9 -69 -62 ] 
[ 1 10 -65 -58 ]  
[ 1 11 -69 -58 ]]
```

Tried with numpy.array but could'nt get the desired output.

Hopefully, that makes some sense :)

Thanks so much! Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What exactly did you try? What output did you get?

Comment: tried using numpy.loadtxt by which I can take the value.Got output as 1 complete array instead of the desired array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.genfromtxt` and `split`:

```
In [5]: arr = np.genfromtxt('test.txt')

In [6]: np.array(np.split(arr, arr.size/4))
Out[6]: 
array([[  1.,   4., -69., -64.],
       [  1.,   5., -57., -56.],
       [  1.,   6., -59., -56.],
       [  1.,   7., -69., -61.],
       [  1.,   8., -53., -53.],
       [  1.,   9., -69., -62.],
       [  1.,  10., -65., -58.],
       [  1.,  11., -69., -58.]])
```

Or just use `reshape()` at the first place:

```
In [14]: arr.reshape(arr.size//4, 4)
Out[14]: 
array([[  1.,   4., -69., -64.],
       [  1.,   5., -57., -56.],
       [  1.,   6., -59., -56.],
       [  1.,   7., -69., -61.],
       [  1.,   8., -53., -53.],
       [  1.,   9., -69., -62.],
       [  1.,  10., -65., -58.],
       [  1.,  11., -69., -58.]])
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!Thanks a ton!!

Comment: @ShubhamKuse if this answer answers your question, consider marking it as the accepted answer to help others in future looking at this question

Answer (score 2):

`np.genfromtxt` + `.reshape` is one way:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.genfromtxt('txt.csv')

arr.reshape((len(arr)/4, 4))

# array([[  1.,   4., -69., -64.],
#        [  1.,   5., -57., -56.],
#        [  1.,   6., -59., -56.],
#        [  1.,   7., -69., -61.],
#        [  1.,   8., -53., -53.],
#        [  1.,   9., -69., -62.],
#        [  1.,  10., -65., -58.],
#        [  1.,  11., -69., -58.]])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have an array by using `numpy.array` as you mentioned, say in a variable called `nums`, then you could do the following:

```
nums = nums.reshape(-1, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> np.genfromtxt('so.txt').reshape(-1,4)
array([[  1.,   4., -69., -64.],
       [  1.,   5., -57., -56.],
       [  1.,   6., -59., -56.],
       [  1.,   7., -69., -61.],
       [  1.,   8., -53., -53.],
       [  1.,   9., -69., -62.],
       [  1.,  10., -65., -58.],
       [  1.,  11., -69., -58.]])
```

Comment: liked yours better @Kasramvd